# Is it possible to "debug" an application on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am working on an ASP .Net Core C # application.
In Visual Studio 2019, I do some debugging, of course.
On localhost, my system is functioning normally, but on the server only the static pages. My question is: can I somehow 'debug' my site on the server. to check the error?

Comment: Yes! There's a nice how-to written by MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-computer?view=vs-2019

Comment: Your server-process is just a normal process which you can attach to.

Comment: Remote debugging is a thing. But i'd first check your config file, its probably an error there. 
Have it display all errors: `customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"` and `httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly"`
If nothing works, delete stuff from your config file until the page loads.
Also set some global error handlers to log errors.